# In yii how to open pdf files and images in lightbox..?

Tags: javascript, php, yii

i need to open image files and pdf files all are in one lightbox. my pdf files are not shown in any lightbox .all r shown error only.below i have Given the code.my image is displayed in lightbox,but pdf is not shown in lightbox.

```
             <?php 
              $this->beginWidget('ext.prettyPhoto.PrettyPhoto', array
                     ( 'id'=>'pretty_photo',
                      // prettyPhoto options
                      'options'=>array(
                        'opacity'=>0.60,
                        'modal'=>true,
                      ),
                    ));
                ?>

                <a href="images/image1.jpg" rel="prettyphoto">image</a>
                <a href="images/sample.pdf" rel="prettyphoto">PDF</a>

                <?php
                $this->endWidget('ext.prettyPhoto.PrettyPhoto');
                 ?>
```

any idea...? or give some other code to show pdf files in lightbox.
 thanks in advance.

Comment: try colorbox  http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/jcolorbox/